# Kendo MVVM Jquery AJAX

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I'm sorry if this has been asked before but every ajax example I find for Kendo has something to do with the grid. I'm new to Kendo and am trying to do a basic ajax call to one of my methods in my controller but I can't seem to populate the span with the data. The 'Name' displays in my alert so I know the data is there...but not in my view.

```
        var viewModel = kendo.observable({
            Text: "SomeText"        
        });
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/GetPerson",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                $.extend(viewModel, data);
                alert(data.Name) //displays correctly.

            }
        })

        kendo.bind(document.body, viewModel);
```

and in my view I have this:

```
<span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated...I'm up for ideas if there is a better way to accomplish this.

**EDIT**

Ok -- I was able to get it working by modifying the code slightly to this, but it seems clunky. Is there a cleaner way?

```
       var viewModel = kendo.observable({
            AjaxData: null        
        });
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/GetPerson",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                viewModel.set("AjaxData", data);
                alert(data.Name) //displays correctly.

            }
        })

        kendo.bind(document.body, viewModel);
```

View:

```
<span data-bind="text: AjaxData.Name"></span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your kendo.bind function before the Ajax call.

I tested this and it works:

```
$(document.body).html('<span data-bind="text: Text"></span>');
var viewModel = kendo.observable({Text: "test 1"});
kendo.bind(document.body, viewModel);
alert("The text now is " + viewModel.Text);
$.ajax({
  url: "/Home/GetPerson",
  dataType: "json",
  type: "POST",
  success: function (data) {
    for ( var n in data ){
      viewModel.set(n, data[n]);
    }
    alert("The text now is " + viewModel.Text);
  }
});
```